# Ubuntu 18.04: how do I enable the Japanese keyboard and conversion to Hiragana?

Tags: ibus, input-language, japanese

I am new to Ubuntu. I downloaded 18.04 and have struggled to get the Japanese conversion working.  I saw many older answers on this forum.  In the end I found my solution on [this page](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/04/29/ubuntu-1804-ibus-mozc-ja/) on a Japanese web site.

I thought I would share it; it is in Japanese but the screen shots are very good.

Answer (score 2):

Using Gnome/Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Install Japanese language for your SO:

   References in [Writing Japanese with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver](https://moritzmolch.com/2404) and [Japanese Input](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JapaneseInput).

   The path to install:

   **System Settings > Region & Language > Manage Installed Languages > Language Support > Install / Remove Languages > Installed Languages** and check **Japanese**. Click **Apply** and log out.
2. Install at least one of the below IMF (`ibus` comes by default on Ubuntu):

   ```
   sudo apt install ibus
   sudo apt install fcitx
   ```
3. Install at least one IME for your IMF (`mozc` comes by default on Ubuntu after install the japanese language):

   If you chose `ibus` run one of these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install ibus-mozc
   sudo apt install ibus-anthy
   sudo apt install ibus-kkc
   sudo apt install ibus-skk
   ```

   If you chose `fcitx` run one of these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
   sudo apt install fcitx-anthy
   sudo apt install fcitx-kkc
   sudo apt install fcitx-skk
   ```

After all of that, select the input method (IME) from your language selector on icon tray (IMF).

The IMF (`ibus`) on `Gnome Status Menu` (is represented by a language icon selector).

All selectable IMEs (portuguese, spanish, english, japanese-mozc, japanese-anthy, japanese-kkc, japanese-skk) from this IMF (`ibus`).

[image: ibus menu and selectables IMEs]

Using the Gnome shortcut to fast-switch between IMEs: hold <kbd>Super</kbd> and press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image: gnome menu shortcut to select IMEs]

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the Mosz keyboard but that does not seem to work. what worked for me was adding the Anthy keyboard.